# Generating a list of all permutations of a given character set between a minimum and maximum amount of characters

Tags: java, string, algorithm, permutation

I am trying to generate a list of all permutations of a given character set between a specified minimum and maximum amount of characters in Java, for use in a password cracking program. For example, with a character set of `ab`, a minimum number of characters of 2 and a maximum number of characters of 4, this would be the output:

```
aa
ab
ba
bb
aaa
aab
aba
baa
abb
bab
bba
bbb
aaaa
aaab
aaba
abaa
baaa
aabb
abab
baab
abbb
babb
bbbb
bbba
bbab
baba
bbaa
abba
```

I am stumped and can't think of a way to do this efficiently and without duplicates. What is the best recursive algorithm for doing this given a `String` for the character set, an `int` for the minimum number of characters, and an `int` for the maximum number of characters?

Here is the pseudo-code for what I am trying to do:

```
//1.start at the minimum number of characters with all characters at index 0
//2.increment rightmost by 1 until last char is reached
//3.shift left by 1
//4.increment this char by 1 unless last char is reached
//5.repeat step 2
//6.repeat step 3
//7.repeat step 4; if last char is reached repeat step 3
//8.when you can't shift left anymore go to the next number of characters, unless the maximum has been reached
```

All I need to do is figure out how to translate this into a recursive method.

Comment: Think of it as if you were counting.  For example if the character set was 0-9, and the length range was two to four.  Just count up.  You can do the same thing treating the character range as an array of char and the index into the array as digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward version is to use a single recursive call for each letter, keeping track of the depth. Then make a recursive call for each length from min to max:

```
char[] letterBank;
// Read in the chars and separate them into a char array

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

void populateMyList(int depth, String stringSoFar) {
  if (depth == 0) {
    myList.add(stringSoFar)
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < letterBank.length; i++) {
    populateMyList(depth - 1, stringSoFar + letterBank[i]);
  }
}

main() {
  for(int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    populateMyList(i, "");
}
```

Note that if you want efficiency then use a StringBuilder and not a string as a parameter.